# ReactJS Update DIV from array of divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a list of items dynamically without having to redo a bunch of code.

When the component mounts, I do this..

```
componentDidMount() {
    {this.listAllActivities(this.props.items)}
}
```

The listAllActivities function is below. I am mapping through an array, pushing elements into a items array and then I return when I am done.

```
listAllActivities(arr){
    let items = [];
    var self = this;
    const grouped = this.groupBy(arr, date => getDateServiceTab(date.date));
    grouped.forEach(function(value, key) {
        value.map((map) => {

            items.push(<div className="row content-timeline" key={map.id}>

              <div className="col-1 activityIcon tooltip2">{self.activityIcon(map.source.toString().toLowerCase())}
              <div className="tooltiptext">{map.source.replace("_", " ")}</div>
              </div>

              <div className="col-11">
                <span className="recentActivityTagHeader">{map.tag === undefined ? map.source : map.tag} <span className="smallGrey">({map.mtn === undefined ? "ACCT" : map.mtn.substr(map.mtn.length - 4)})</span></span>
                <div className="recentActivityDescription">{map.source === "OCC_LL" || map.source === "OCC_AL" ? self.configureOCCCredit(map.description) : map.description}</div>
                <div className="recentActivityDate">{styleDateTime(map.date)}</div>
              </div>

            </div>)
        })
    })
    $('thisdiv').append(items).html()
    return items;
}
```

I am then sticking `<div id="thisdiv"></div>` where I need this info to be updated.

How can I update the thisdiv ID with the items within with items array from the function?

UPDATE

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import acss from '../image/activity/acss.png';
import app from '../image/activity/app.png';
import chatbot from '../image/activity/chatbot.png';
import email from '../image/activity/email.png';
import icm from '../image/activity/icm.png';
import impact from '../image/activity/impact.png';
import ivr from '../image/activity/ivr.png';
import netace from '../image/activity/netace.png';
import network from '../image/activity/network.png';
import retail from '../image/activity/retail.png';
import sms from '../image/activity/sms.png';
import vision from '../image/activity/vision.png';
import web from '../image/activity/web.png';
import occ from '../image/activity/occ.png';
import plus from '../image/plus.png';
import minus from '../image/minus.png';

import { getDateServiceTab, styleDateTime } from "../GlobalFunctions";

class AccordionSection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        {this.listAllActivities(this.props.items)}
    }
    groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
        const map = new Map();
        list.forEach((item) => {
             const key = keyGetter(item);
             const collection = map.get(key);
             if (!collection) {
                 map.set(key, [item]);
             } else {
                 collection.push(item);
             }
        });
        return map;
    };

    configureOCCCredit(description) {
        return("$" + description)           
    }

    activityIcon(tag) {
        switch(tag) {
          case "acss": return <img src={acss} />
          case "app": return <img src={app}  />
          case "chatbot": return <img src={chatbot} />
          case "email": return <img src={email} />
          case "icm": return <img src={icm}  />
          case "impact": return <img src={impact}/>
          case "ivr": return <img src={ivr} />
          case "ivr_utterance": return <img src={ivr} />
          case "netace": return <img src={netace}  />
          case "network": return <img src={network} />
          case "retail": return <img src={retail} />
          case "retail store": return <img src={retail} />
          case "sms": return <img src={sms} />
          case "vision": return <img src={vision} />
          case "web": return <img src={web} />
          case "occ": return <img src={occ} />
          case "occ_ll": return <img src={occ} />
          case "occ_al": return <img src={occ} />
        }

      }


    itemsArray(arr) {
        let items = [];
        let self = this;
        const grouped = this.groupBy(arr, item => item.source);
        grouped.forEach(function(value, key) {
            if(key === "IVR_UTTERANCE") {key = "IVR"}



            switch(key.toString().toLowerCase()) {
            case "acss": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={acss} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "app": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={app} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "chatbot": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={chatbot} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "email": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={email} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "icm": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={icm} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "impact": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={impact} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "ivr": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={ivr} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "ivr_utterance": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={ivr} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "netace": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={netace} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "network": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={network} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "retail": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={retail} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "retail store": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={retail} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "sms": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={sms} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "vision": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={vision} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "web": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={web} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "occ": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={occ} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "occ_ll": return items.push(<div className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={occ} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
            case "occ_al": return items.push(<div onClick={() => self.listAllActivities(value)}  className="recentActivityChannels"><img src={occ} width="15" /><span>{value.length < 10 ? "0" + value.length : value.length}</span></div>)
          }

        })
        items.push(<div className="clearFloat"></div>);
        return items;
    }

    listAllActivities(arr){
        let items = [];
        var self = this;
        const grouped = this.groupBy(arr, date => getDateServiceTab(date.date));
        grouped.forEach(function(value, key) {
            value.map((map) => {

                items.push(<div className="row content-timeline" key={map.id}>

                  <div className="col-1 activityIcon tooltip2">{self.activityIcon(map.source.toString().toLowerCase())}
                  <div className="tooltiptext">{map.source.replace("_", " ")}</div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-11">
                    <span className="recentActivityTagHeader">{map.tag === undefined ? map.source : map.tag} <span className="smallGrey">({map.mtn === undefined ? "ACCT" : map.mtn.substr(map.mtn.length - 4)})</span></span>
                    <div className="recentActivityDescription">{map.source === "OCC_LL" || map.source === "OCC_AL" ? self.configureOCCCredit(map.description) : map.description}</div>
                    <div className="recentActivityDate">{styleDateTime(map.date)}</div>
                  </div>

                </div>)
            })
        })
        $('thisdiv').append(items).html()
        return items;
    }



  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired,
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.label);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onClick,
      props: { isOpen, label, items },
    } = this;




    return (
      <div
        style={{
          background: '#fff',
        }}
      >
      {/*onClick={onClick}*/}
        <div style={{ padding: '15px 30px 10px 30px',borderBottom: isOpen ? '1px solid #000' : '1px solid #cdcdcd', }}>
          <div><span style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>{label}</span>
          <div onClick={onClick}  style={{ float: 'right', cursor:'pointer' }}>
            {!isOpen && <span><img src={plus} width="14"/></span>}
            {isOpen && <span><img src={minus} width="14"/></span>}
          </div>
          </div>

          <div className="recentActivityChannelsPadding">
          {this.itemsArray(items)}
          </div>

        </div>
        {isOpen && (
          <div
            style={{
              background: '#F9F9F9',
              borderBottom: '1px solid #D5D7D7',
              padding: '10px 30px',
            }}
          >

          <div id="thisdiv"></div>


          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AccordionSection;
```

this is based off of https://alligator.io/react/react-accordion-component/

Comment: This logic should be implemented inside the `render` function. Could you post that part of the code (preferably the whole component class)?

Comment: @jmkmay updated

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do here? Inside `componentDidMount` you aren't actually doing anything. `{listAllActivities(arr)}` is just a statement. If you want to render that array of `divs` you have to use that inside another tag in `return` from `render` EDIT: ohh I see `<div id="thisdiv"></div>` exists in render. Ok hold on...

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jquery with reactjs?

Comment: no. just trying to get this to work, and then i said, "self, lets try updating the div with jquery". Normally i would set the state, but it wont set. the items are stores in this.props.items

Comment: use state in your component to store the items or call your function in the div. Your componentDidMount do nothing. BTW that code needs a hard refactor.

Comment: @F.bernal i cant set state.......trying to figure that out as well.... look at the website i posed...maybe u can see something i dont.

Comment: @soldfor I'll write up a couple suggestions when I get home from work. In the meantime I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with controlling components through state and refs. I've yet to encounter a problem in react which can't be solved using state and refs. You can set state in your constructor based on props.

Comment: @jmkmay  thanks for the efforts.